# Replicating Snowbird's Animation Effect

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, graph

Snowbird (http://www.snowbird.com/) does some really cool stuff on their site. One of the things I love is when you hover over the black panel on the right, another panel flips out and then the charts count up and the orange graph "rotates" to its final position. I'd like to replicate the orange bar rotating in the graph with either CSS3 or JS. It looks like they may be using the `canvas` element, which I have never used before, but would be open to it. Any thoughts on the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are using a canvas for that.
Here's a starting point:

```
var c = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
var duration = 700; // duration of animation
var delay = 10; // interval
var stepT = duration/delay; // steps needed
var cT = 0; // step counter

c.fillStyle = 'white'
var end = 58; // endpoint in percent

var int = setInterval(function(){
    c.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
    c.strokeStyle = 'orange';
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(50, 50, 40, -.5*Math.PI, (-.5*Math.PI + 2*Math.PI / 100 * end * cT / stepT));
    c.lineWidth = 10;
    c.stroke();
    if(++cT>stepT){
        clearInterval(int);   
    }
},delay);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SCk6B/

---

Version 2 with multiple circles:

```
<canvas class="circle" data-duration="700" data-end="75" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<canvas class="circle" data-duration="200" data-end="50" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<canvas class="circle" data-duration="500" data-end="20" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

```
$('.circle').each(function(){
    var duration = $(this).data('duration') || 700; // duration of animation
    var delay = 10; // interval
    var stepT = duration/delay; // steps needed
    var cT = 0; // step countervar
    var end = $(this).data('end') || 58; // endpoint in percent
    var int = null;
    var c = this.getContext('2d');
    c.fillStyle = 'white';
    c.lineWidth = 10;
    c.strokeStyle = 'orange';
     $(this).bind('mouseenter',function(){
        int = setInterval(function(){
            c.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(50, 50, 40, -.5*Math.PI, (-.5*Math.PI + 2*Math.PI / 100 * end * cT / stepT));
            c.stroke();
            if(++cT>stepT){
                clearInterval(int);   
            }
        },delay);
    }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
        clearInterval(int);
        c.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
        cT=0;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3BPP/

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks @Andy! Do you have a good resource to check out to learn more about canvas?

Comment: @Andrew sorry, i don't have a single go-to page for canvas but a google search will bring up many resource and tutorial pages. For example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial

Comment: okay great. I have started digging through some of those but wasn't sure if you had any other resources. No worries. Also, two follow-up questions with it: 1) how would you make this work on hover so the animation resets when you hover off and starts again when you hover over again? Right now I have it in a hover function and it runs when you hover over it, but then doesn't run again when you hover off and back on. 2) how can you make the function resuable? I have 6 of these elements I want to animate and I'd like to reuse the function (while changing duration). Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew sure, i made a second version.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much. Using the data attribute is a great idea. Thank you for your help!